# How to model the associations properly in rails to perform inner joins in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following models

```
class RecruitmentPhase < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :cohort, optional: true
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'Cohort', required: false
  has_many :patient_phases, dependent: :destroy, class_name: 'PatientPhase', foreign_key: :phase_id, primary_key: :phase_id
  has_many :patients, through: :patient_phases, class_name: 'Patient', foreign_key: :patient_id, primary_key: :patient_id

  def phase_name_ret
    phase_name
  end
end
```

```
class PatientPhase < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :patients, foreign_key: 'patient_id', class_name: 'Patient', primary_key: 'patient_id'
  belongs_to :recruitment_phase, foreign_key: :phase_id
  self.primary_key = :phase_id
end
```

```
class Patient < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :patient_phases, foreign_key: 'patient_id', primary_key: :patient_id
  belongs_to :patient_phase
  has_one :recruitment_phase, through: :patient_phase
end
```

and my schema is as follows

```
  create_table "recruitment_phases", options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "phase_id"
    t.string "phase_token"
    t.string "phase_name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.bigint "source_id"
    t.bigint "cohort_id"
    t.index ["cohort_id"], name: "index_recruitment_phases_on_cohort_id"
    t.index ["source_id"], name: "index_recruitment_phases_on_source_id"
  end
```

```
  create_table "patients", options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "patient_id"
    t.integer "recruitment_code_id"
    t.string "disease_code_id"
    t.string "sex"
    t.integer "yob"
    t.date "date_imported"
    t.integer "is_exported"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.bigint "patient_phase_id"
    t.index ["patient_phase_id"], name: "index_patients_on_patient_phase_id"
  end
```

```
  create_table "patient_phases", id: false, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "patient_id"
    t.integer "phase_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.bigint "recruitment_phase_id"
    t.index ["recruitment_phase_id"], name: "index_patient_phases_on_recruitment_phase_id"
  end
```

I am trying to perform joins on the tables as follows in rails console

```
 RecruitmentPhase.joins(:patient_phases, :patients).where(:patients => {disease_code_id: 'KIN'}).select('distinct patients.disease_code_id', 'recruitment_phases.phase_name', 'recruitment_phases.phase_id')
```

And I am getting the translated query to SQL as

```
 SELECT  distinct disease_code_id FROM `recruitment_phases`
     INNER JOIN `patient_phases` ON `patient_phases`.`phase_id` = `recruitment_phases`.`phase_id`
     INNER JOIN `patient_phases` `patient_phases_recruitment_phases_join` ON `patient_phases_recruitment_phases_join`.`phase_id` = `recruitment_phases`.`phase_id`
     INNER JOIN `patients` ON `patients`.`patient_id` = `patient_phases_recruitment_phases_join`.`patient_id`
    WHERE `patients`.`disease_code_id` = 'KIN' LIMIT 11
```

But I need the query as follows

```
 SELECT  distinct patients.disease_code_id,
                  recruitment_phases.phase_name, recruitment_phases.phase_id FROM `patients`
                      join patient_phases on patient_phases.patient_id = patients.patient_id
                      join recruitment_phases on recruitment_phases.phase_id = patient_phases.phase_id
                      WHERE (patients.disease_code_id = 'KIN') LIMIT 11
```

I know some how my associations are not correct, as I am a trying to learn more on such concepts, can you give me a hint on how I can approach the above problem?.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my question. It was just using the following

```
RecruitmentPhase.joins(patients: :patient_phases).where(:patients => {disease_code_id: 'KIN'}).select('distinct patients.disease_code_id', 'recruitment_phases.phase_name', 'recruitment_phases.phase_id')
```